# Select all records except max record in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
login_id    product_name  price    bid_price

123         onion         500      515
150         onion         500      517
115         tomato        475      580
120         potato        399      410
145         potato        399      413
145         potato        399      405
```

And I need to select those records which product_name which has multiple bids and not max bid per product

**Expected Result:**

```
login_id    product_name  price    bid_price

123         onion         500      515
120         potato        399      410
145         potato        399      405
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by porduct_name order by bid_price desc) rn
from t1
) select * from cte where rn<>1



 login_id   porduct_name    price   bid_price
   123          onion           500     515
   120          potato          399     410
   145          potato          399     405
```

Comment: This is probably the most optimal solution on SQL Server +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen after your comment i also tried this one and yes this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf905fab4862349a5b92454dbdc35789)**

```
select * from tablename a 
where not exists 
  (select 1 from tablename b where a.product_name=b.product_name
         group by b.product_name having count(bid_price)=1)
and bid_price not in 
    (select max(bid_price) from tablename c where a.product_name=c.product_name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
login_id    porduct_name    price   bid_price
123         onion           500     515
120         potato          399     410
145         potato          399     405
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join on the highest bids for each product and select everything else

```
select t.*
from your_table t
left join 
(
    select product_name, max(bid_price) as maxbid
    from your_table
    group by product_name
) tmp on tmp.product_name = t.product_name
     and tmp.maxbid = t.bid_price
where tmp.product_name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Common Table Expression`

```
with cte_test1
as
(
    select t.product_name, count(*) [RowsCount],max(t.bid_price) [max_bid_price]
    from dbo.Test001 t
    group by t.product_name
)

select *
from dbo.Test001 t
join cte_test1 c on c.product_name=t.product_name
where c.RowsCount>1 and t.bid_price<c.max_bid_price
```